# Why neither navigation buttons nor pips are visible?

Tags: winui-3

```
<StackPanel>
    <FlipView x:Name="FlipView" Loaded="OnFlipsViewLoaded" >
        <view:A/>
        <view:B/>
        <view:C/>
        <view:D/>
        <view:E/>
    </FlipView>
    <PipsPager NumberOfPages="5"
               SelectedPageIndex="{x:Bind Path=FlipView.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
               PreviousButtonVisibility="Visible"
               NextButtonVisibility="Visible"
               Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I enable the navigation buttons but the ones and the pips are missing in the footer below the pips pages. Here you can see, the first page loaded but the control's footer part - as it is horizontal - went missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PipsPager` should be under the `FlipView` but might not be visible because of the `FlipView` height.

Using `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` works on my side:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
    <FlipView
        x:Name="FlipView"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Loaded="FlipView_Loaded">
        <view:A />
        <view:B />
        <view:C />
        <view:D />
        <view:E />
    </FlipView>
    <PipsPager
        Grid.Row="1"
        NextButtonVisibility="Visible"
        NumberOfPages="5"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        PreviousButtonVisibility="Visible"
        SelectedPageIndex="{x:Bind Path=FlipView.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```